# What is the difference between "reborrow"-ing and "deref"-ing?

Tags: rust, immutability, dereference, borrow-checker, rust-clippy

Clippy is warning me about a "deref on an immutable reference" in my code, an example being `&*s` where `s` is a `&String`.

Clippy suggests,

> if you would like to reborrow, try removing `&*`

or

> if you would like to deref, try using `&**`

What is the difference between these two suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that `Deref` is a trait. If `T: Deref<Target=U>`, it means that `T` can be seen as a pointer to `U` (roughly). This entails that Rust will automatically transform a `&T` into a `&U` if it needs to (ie. if you are calling a method of `U` on a value of type `T`). This also triggers when you try to deference `T`: Rust will `deref` it into `U`.

However, this is not the case here: you are dereferencing `&String`, which will give a `String` (without even thinking about `String` as a pointer to `str`, because `String: Deref<Target=str>`), then you borrow that thing again. If your objective was to end up with a `&str`, you failed. Which is why Rust proposes to to deference once again: `&** &String -> &* String -> &* &str -> & str -> &str`.

---

Or, maybe you wanted to do something called reborrow, which has nothing to do with dereferencing. Reborrow is needed when you have a certain kind of borrow, and you need an other kind of borrow. For instance, if you have a `&mut T` and wanted a `&T`, you could reborrow. Note that a reborrow always specifically means dereferencing a borrow, just to borrow it again: it will not trigger a deref or anything like that, it's just a type-checking step (in practice, a reborrow won't produce any code, it's just for the compiler to reason about; whereas a deref will produce some code).

An example of why you would want to do that is to change the implicit lifetime bounded to a borrow: when you reborrow, you are authorized to have a give smaller lifetime to the new borrow, which allows you to reuse the original borrow once you're done with the reborrowed one. See an example provided by @Cerberus on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a7b329f2d48c8e7bc6a24d24d34256c9):

```rust
use core::fmt::Debug;

fn debug(val: impl Debug) {
    dbg!(val);
}

fn debug_ref(val: &impl Debug) {
    dbg!(val);
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 42;
    let x_ref = &mut x;
    
    // fails to compile - `x_ref` is moved into `debug`,
    // but later we use it again
    // debug(x_ref);
    
    // compiles successfully
    debug(&mut *x_ref);
    
    // also compiles successfully, since the target type is reference,
    // so `x_ref` is implicitly reborrowed
    debug_ref(x_ref);
    
    *x_ref = 84;
    debug(x_ref);
}
```

However, in your case, you would transform a regular borrow (that Clippy calls "immutable borrow") into a regular borrow: you're doing nothing! Which is why Clippy suggests that you remove that altogether.

Comment: @Cerberus thanks for the example, I add it accordingly.